# Java shifting bytes returns an unexpected result

Tags: java, byte, short, byte-shifting

I am trying to shift 2 bytes into a short. These 2 bytes represent an unsigned short that in turn represents a port. I've tried multiple ways to shift these bytes into a short on java. However, I constantly fail to do this correctly.

These are the ways I've tried:

```
byte a = 0x17;
byte b = 0xCC;

(short)((a << 8) | b);
(short)(((short)a << 8) | b);
```

The result is 0xFFCC, but should be 0x17CC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any value that undergoes arithmetic in Java, is first cast to higher type which could cover both operands. Both of operands  are cast to `int` if they are still smaller.

As a result, `b` is first cast to `int` and becomes `0xFFFFFFCC`. Or-ing it with anything shifted by 8 bits to the left always keeps the mask `0xFFFFFF00` and therefore has no impact on result. Casting it to short just shrinks off the left 16 bits.

To resolve it, explicitly mask with `0xFF` before doing the operation:

```
(short)(((a&0xFF)<<8)|(b&0xFF))
```

Answer (score 0):

//Try this, since you cannot convert from int to byte:

`short a = 0x17;`
`short b = 0xCC;`
`System.out.println("r = " + String.format("0x%04X",  (short)((a << 8) | b)));`

//Output: r = 0x17CC